# Find back slash (\) in C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with count number of back slash `\` in C++, I have this code:

```
string path = "a\b\c";
int level = 0;
int path_length = path.size();
for(int i = 0; i < path_length; i++){
if(path.at(i) == '\\'){
        level++;
    }
}
cout << level << endl;
```

However, the level is always 0! Can you explain why? And how to count the number of `/`?

Comment: The code you provided should work well for forward slashes('/'), except that you should remember NOT to escape them anywhere like you have done for the backslashes above(and BTW, you missed escaping the backslashes in "a\b\c" - it should read "a\\b\\c".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backslashes in your variable should be escaped.

```
string path = "a\\b\\c";
```

Also you can use `count` function in algorithms library to avoid looping each character in the string and check whether it is backslash.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>   // for count()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string path = "a\\b\\c";
int no_of_backslash = (int)count(path.begin(), path.end(), '\\');
cout << "no of backslash " << no_of_backslash << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Your string is <del>invalid</del> not what you expect it to be - it should be `string path = "a\\b\\c";`

You even get warnings (or at least MSVS provides warnings):

> warning C4129: 'c' : unrecognized character escape sequence